# Skill List with pages

Tags: javascript, mongoose, discord, discord.js

I have a list with like 40 different skills and what I'd like to do is printing out 10 of them on one page and then next 10 in the list on the next page and so on. I want people to type `!list [page]` so like `!list 2` for the second page of skills. I assume I need to store all skills except the 10 on that list, but I have no idea how to go about that. Thanks.

```
    let text = ""

    const skillDB = await Skill.find({
    }).sort({
        skillRarity: -1
    })

        for (let i = 0; i < skillDB.length; ++i) {

            text += `\`${skillDB[i].skillSymbol}\` ${skillDB[i].skillName}\n`
        }

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(text)
        return message.channel.send(embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array's [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method for pagination. It returns a copy of a portion of the original array into a new array from the start index to the end.

Check the following examples:

```js
function paginate({ array, size = 5, page = 1 }) {
  return array.slice((page - 1) * size, page * size);
}

console.log(paginate({
  array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  size: 3,
  // first page
}));
console.log(paginate({
  array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  size: 3,
  page: 2
}));
console.log(paginate({
  array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  size: 4,
  page: 3
}));
```

In your code it would look like this:

```js
let text = '';
const page = parseInt(args[0], 10);
const size = 10;

// probably check if page is valid

const skillsDB = await Skill.find({}).sort({ skillRarity: -1 });
const skills = skillsDB.slice((page - 1) * size, page * size);

for (let skill of skills) {
  text += `\`${skill.skillSymbol}\` ${skill.skillName}\n`;
}

const embed = new MessageEmbed().setDescription(text);
return message.channel.send(embed);
```

You could also work with Mongoose directly. You can use [`.skip()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-skip) and [`.limit()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit) to limit the number of results and to skip some pages:

```js
const perPage = 10;
const page = args[0] >= 1 ? args[0] - 1 : 0;
const skills = await Skill.find({})
  .sort({ skillRarity: -1 })
  .limit(perPage)
  .skip(perPage * page);

if (!skills.length) {
  return message.channel.send('Looks like that page does not exist.');
}

const text = skills
  .map((skill) => `${skill.skillSymbol} ${skill.skillName}`)
  .join('\n');

const embed = new MessageEmbed().setDescription(text);
return message.channel.send(embed);
```